# How to loop through tasks in Windows cmd and only output task if it is NOT in a list?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to output unneeded tasks to the Windows command line. The end result should be that I basically kill all unneeded tasks with the click of a button. But to avoid any problems I am outputting the tasks names for now. I know there is other ways like disabling them on `msconfig` or `regedit`, but for now this is what I want.

The problem is I have been away from console usage for a long time and it has left me slightly confused. I have code below that outputs all running tasks, but it doesn't stop outputting the tasks in the `mylist` array. I think the problem is my nested `for` loop, but I don't know any other ways of passing the two arrays to one list so that I can check them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
@echo off
set mylist=csrss.exe, dwm.exe, System, smss.exe Rem<<List
for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('tasklist') do ( Rem<<This returns process name
    for %%b in ('%mylist%') do ( Rem<<b is MEANT to be each process in list
        if not %%a == %%b ( Rem<<If anything in tasklist is in mylist, don't include it
            echo %%a) Rem<<Output processes NOT in mylist.
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: There are not arrays in batch file! Also, I can't understand: `if not %%a == %%b`. `tasklist` will give you 5 columns, each one is one token (if `exe` name is one word, but here `exe` you have provided are one word.). 1st column is the `image name` and second column is `PID`. They won't be equal in NO ONE case.

Comment: Yes but there are some ways of making arrays in a batch file, look at this link, I am trying to basically recreate this method of outputting numbers for the .exe files https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_arrays.htm

Comment: This can be called "array"?

Comment: there are two main errors in your code: your 2nd `for` should not have `'` (you don't want to execute a command, but process a list); Every line of `tasklist` will be shown at least three times (you have four strings in your list, each filename from `tasklist` will be at least different from three of them. The second one is a logical error, which needs code redesign.

Comment: @double-beep, KieranBrown: this is not an array, but a list.

Comment: Then I was taught wrong double-beep, the title has been changed and comments have been added to make my purpose a little more clear, thank you for clearing that up. Also thanks @Stephan, my mistakes are a lot more obvious now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's much easier with the help of `findstr`:

```
@echo off
set "mylist=csrss.exe dwm.exe System smss.exe"
for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ('tasklist^|findstr /biv "%mylist%"') do echo %%a 
pause
```

`findstr` switches:
- **b** = beginning of the line
- **i** = ignore capitalization (optional)
- **v** = exclude the given string(s)

Comment: What I actually don't like in this approach is that you can't specify list items with spaces, but that's already a flaw of the OP's concept; I'd probably put the given process names into a text file, one name per line and use `findstr`'s `/G` option; of course `tokens=1` needed to be changed then...

Answer (score 2):

One more solution:

```
@echo off
echo Running tasks not in list:
echo/
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "mylist=,csrss.exe,dwm.exe,System,smss.exe,cmd.exe,tasklist.exe,"
for /F "skip=3 eol=| tokens=1" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\system32\tasklist.exe') do (
    if "!mylist:,%%I,=!" == "!mylist!" echo %%I
)
endlocal
pause
```

First, there is the environment variable `mylist` defined with each process name separated by a comma including first and last.

**FOR** runs in a separate command process started with `cmd.exe /C` in background the command line:

```
C:\Windows\system32\tasklist.exe
```

This console application outputs all running tasks with two header lines and usually `System Idle Process` as first process to handle **STDOUT** of background command process.

**FOR** captures this output and processes it line by line with skipping empty lines and additionally also always the first three lines because of `skip=3`.

It is very unusual, but nevertheless possible, that an executable file name starts with `;` which is the default character for end of line option of **FOR**. For that reason `eol=|` redefines the vertical bar as end of line character which no file name can contain resulting in no process line ignored by **FOR**.

`tokens=1` results in first space/tab separating string being assigned to specified loop variable `I`. So this solution works only for processes of which file name does not contain a space character.

**FOR** runs **IF** which does a case-sensitive string comparison. The left string is the string value assigned to environment variable `mylist` with all occurrences of current process name surrounded by a comma on both sides case-insensitive replaced by nothing. The right string is the unmodified string value assigned to environment variable `mylist`.

So the current process name is not in list on left string being equal right string because of nothing removed from left string. In this case the process name is output.

`cmd.exe` and `tasklist.exe` are always in list and should be therefore always included in string assigned to environment variable `mylist`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: `TASKLIST /NH /FO CSV` would allow spaces in name (but require mylist entries to be d'quoted) and also remove the header (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Since task/image names might also contain <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>, I recommend not to use a <kbd>SPACE</kbd>-separated list of exclusions; instead I would put the items in a text file, one item per line, like this, for instance:

> ```cmd
> csrss.exe
> dwm.exe
> System
> smss.exe
> ```

Then I would write a list of plain image names extracted from the output of [`tasklist`](http://ss64.com/nt/tasklist.html) into a temporary file, which I would filter by the [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), like this:

```cmd
@echo off
set "_LIST=%~1"
set "_TMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp"

> "%_TMPF%" (
    for /F delims^=^"^ eol^=^" %%P in ('
        tasklist /FO CSV /NH
    ') do @(
        echo(%%P
    )
)
findstr /VIXG:"%_LIST%" "%_TMPF%"
del "%_TMPF%"
```

The list file can be specified as a command line argument here.

Or you could also avoid the temporary file and use this slightly more complex code instead:

```cmd
@echo off
set "_LIST=%~1"

(
    for /F delims^^^=^^^"^^^ eol^^^=^^^" %%P in ('
        tasklist /FO CSV /NH
    ') do @(
        echo(%%P^& rem/
    )
) | findstr /VIXG:"%_LIST%"
```

---

If you do want to embed the list items in the batch file, you could do it like in the following example:

```cmd
@echo off
set "_TMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp"

> "%_TMPF%" (
    for /F delims^=^"^ eol^=^" %%P in ('
        tasklist /FO CSV /NH
    ') do @(
        echo ::::%%P
    )
)
for /F "delims=: eol=:" %%Q in ('
    findstr /BC:"::::" "%~f0" ^| findstr /VIXG:/ "%_TMPF%"
') do (
    echo(%%Q
)
del "%_TMPF%"

::LIST ITEMS:
::::csrss.exe
::::dwm.exe
::::System
::::smss.exe
```